# Установка времени на сервере

Tags: время, php, сервер

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как реализовать время на сервере, которое не меняется в зависимости от настроек времени на компьютере.

Comment: чето ваще не понял сути вопроса(

Comment: Можно просто таймер сделать...

Comment: Может, конкретный пример задачи приведёте? А так обычно время сохраняют в UTC (GMT), и переводят в часовой пояс посетителя при необходимости.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмите функцию php, которая может выполнять команды, найти её несложно на сайте [php.net](http://php.net), и получайте время с сервера.

А вообще время на сервере никогда не изменится, несмотря на то, какое оно у вас на компе!

Comment: я согласен со SHREKom
